# Matlab R2015b Mac OS X - plot error using gca

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a very simple function in Matlab R2015b (Mac OS X) like in this web page:

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-high-level-plotting-functions.html

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
figure
plot(x,y)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error using gca
While setting the 'Parent' property of 'Axes':
The value '---' is not a valid line style.

Error in newplot (line 68)
    ax = gca(fig);

Error in my_function (line 4)
plot(x,y)
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: hmm strange, try 'plot(x,y, 'r-')'

Comment: same error: `Error using gca
While setting the 'Parent' property of 'Axes':
The value '---' is not a valid line style.

Error in newplot (line 68)
    ax = gca(fig);

Error in my_function (line 4)
plot(x,y, 'r-')` why is this happening?

Comment: What does `get(groot, 'DefaultLineLineStyle')` yield?

Comment: `>> get(groot, 'DefaultLineLineStyle')

ans =

-`

Comment: Strange indeed: the code snippet works fine for me (same setup: Mac OS X with Matlab R2015b). @adrCoder, are you sure you have XQuartz installed (and working) on your machine?

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it seems to be plotting OK.. Does anyone have an idea why this happened in the first place?!?! -- by the way, thanks to everybody for answering and trying to help.

Comment: @adrCoder I have no idea. Probably a restart of MATLAB would have been sufficient. I have never seen that issue before.

Comment: What made me restart was searching online and some people said that there might be hidden figures or I don't know what, and that a restart might help.. weird !

Comment: I have the same issue on linux, fedora